# Django userena mugshot widget in a form

Tags: django, forms

I would like to add the mugshot in django userena to the initial registration form, along with username, password and email address. I did as said in the faq (http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-add-extra-fields-to-forms) So now I have my own form that inherits the userena signup form. I also redefined the save method to save the new mugshot in the user's profile. But now I don't know how to make that field appear in the form. I could not find any example since userena uses a modelform that automatically renders it. In the same way I can add a text field in this form as forms.CharField I would like to know what I should use to render the mugshot?

Comment: Are you asking how to display the user's mugshot image? Or how to include that field in signup form?. Also post the code you worked, so that it will be easy for the community to help you.

Comment: I was asking how to include that field in the signup form. I will post my code as the answer, I just got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it appears that it is quite easy, just follow the steps described in the userena FAQ to add some extra fields to forms and in the new forms.py put something along the lines:

```
from django import forms    
from userena.forms import SignupForm

class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField()

    def save(self):
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()

        profile = new_user.get_profile()
        profile.mugshot = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        profile.save()

        return new_user
```

Comment: The widget is not required here. Using `forms.ImageField` is enough.